# How to delete breakpoints in XCode

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I go to Breakpoints panel in XCode, in the 'Breakpoints' I click a breakpoint and click 'Delete', but it does not remove the breakpoint.  And I try go to go to 'Project Breakpoints' and find the same breakpoint and click 'Delete'. But it still does not break the breakpoint.

Answer (score 83):

Drag them out of the bar on the side and they will disappear.

[image]

You can also press the shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> while your cursor is on the line, or press <kbd>⌫</kbd> with the breakpoint selected in the navigator:

[image: breakpoint navigator]

Comment: Selecting from the list and pressing the delete key is what worked for me. Dragging from the bar on the side was not an option as nothing was actually being displayed (but code was still breaking on my "invisible" breakpoint, just an item in the breakpoints list. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Also try <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to toggle the breakpoint at the current line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also right-click on it and select the "Delete" menu.