# Objective C printing String

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective C. I'm trying the following:

```
#import "Person.h"
@implementation Person
-(void) setDetails:(NSString*)FirstName :(NSString *)Surname :(int)age{
        _firstName = FirstName;
        _surname = Surname;
        _age = age;
}

-(void) printDetails{
    NSLog(@"The details of the person are FirstName %@, Surname %@, Age %d", _firstName,_surname,_age);
}
@end
```

Main:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Person *noor = [Person new];
        [noor setDetails:@"Noor" :@"Bake" :24];
        [noor printDetails];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting this result: `(lldb)`. I was expecting it to print the details of the person

but it is printing (lldb).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Like someone pointed out, check if you've set a breakpoint or something. As a suggestion, add readable method names. Say -(void) setDetailsWithFirstName:(NSString*)FirstName
                        Surname:(NSString *)Surname
                            Age:(int)age

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you've added a breakpoint. Just remove it will be fine.

[How to delete breakpoints in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353759/how-to-delete-breakpoints-in-xcode)

`(lldb)` is the prompt for debugger.