# Simulator freeze in Swift, breakpoint?

Tags: xcode, swift

iOS rookie here struggling through the early stages of an app that was initially led by a mentor. Issue at the moment occurs upon attempting to button "next" to next page and save the inputted data into firebase. On the simulator, instead of loading to the next page, and inputting data into firebase, it cuts to this code:

```
    @IBAction func greetingSubmit(sender: AnyObject) {
    var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://xxx.firebaseio.com")
    let timestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
    var painAndProgress = ["userID": myRootRef.authData.uid, "pain": painLevelSlider.value, "progress":progressSlider.value, "date":timestamp]
    var painAndProgressRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("painAndProgress")
    var autoRef = painAndProgressRef.childByAutoId()
    autoRef.setValue(painAndProgress)
}
```

On the second to last line, 
        var autoRef = painAndProgressRef.childByAutoId()

There is a message to the right: Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1
which I presume is causing this, but I don't know the fix.

Comment: Is there a blue arrow to the left of that line of code?  If so control-click on it and choose Delete breakpoint from the pop-up.

Comment: xcode is referring to it as an "instruction pointer" and none of the aforementioned breakpoint killing fixes are working.

Comment: There are no breakpoints listed in the Breakpoint Navigator?

Comment: Solved via breakpoint navigator.  Thank you, sir.

Comment: You're welcome, Alex.  The top voted answer did mention the Breakpoint Navigator. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1353759/1630618

Comment: Yes, found that after a second look.  Slowly familiarizing myself with xcode.

Comment: Understandable.  Xcode is quite a beast with many hidden corners.